# Spring 3.1.1 MVC @Cacheable not being hit

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ehcache

I am writing a webapp, and and trying to cache some pojos that are called from the controller.

I wasn't able to get anything working when I tried using org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable, so I switched to com.googlecode.ehcaceh.annotations.Cacheable, and I still can't get it to cache.

My code looks like this:

```
@Controller
 public class Conttroller {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)....
    public Person getPerson(String id) {
        LOG.debug("Trying to get resource...);
        Person person = personService.detect(id);
        LOG.debug("got person");
```

and the service looks like:

```
public class PersonService {

@Cacheable(cacheName="deviceCache") 
public Person detect(String id) {
LOG.debug("cache missed")
```

My applicationContext looks like

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany" />


         <ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" />
         <bean id="cacheManager"      class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
            <property name="cacheManager">
                <ref bean="ehCacheManager" />
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="ehCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:configLocation="/META-INF/ehcache.xml" />
```

and my ehcache looks like:

```
<defaultCache eternal="false" maxElementsInMemory="1000"
    overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false" timeToIdleSeconds="0"
    timeToLiveSeconds="600" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>

<cache name="deviceCache"
    maxElementsInMemory="100" overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="300"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
```

What is interesting is that it caches fine in my unit test...

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:META-INF/applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class PersonServiceTest {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonServiceTest.class);
@Test
public void testCache() {
    LOG.debug("Getting person...");
    Device detect = personService.detect("test");
    LOG.debug("Getting person again ...");
    detect = personService.detect("test");
    LOG.debug("Done");
}
```

which produces:

```
    13:45:02.885 [main] DEBUG PersonServiceTest - Getting person...
13:45:02.887 [main] DEBUG c.g.e.a.i.CacheAttributeSourceImpl - Adding CACHE advised method 'detect' with attribute: CacheableAttributeImpl [cacheInstanceResolver=com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.resolver.SingletonCacheableCacheResolver@5c2bfdff, cacheKeyGenerator=HashCodeCacheKeyGenerator [includeMethod=true, includeParameterTypes=true, useReflection=false, checkforCycles=false], parameterMask=ParameterMask [mask=[]]]
13:45:02.889 [main] DEBUG c.g.e.a.i.EhCacheInterceptor - Generated key '-1043428721379252' for invocation: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public abstract com.mycompany.Person com.mycompany.PersonServiceImpl.detect(java.lang.String); target is of class [com..mycompany.PersonServiceImpl]
13:45:02.889 [main] DEBUG PersonServiceTest - Missed 
13:45:02.927 [main] DEBUG PersonServiceTest  - Getting person again ...
13:45:02.927 [main] DEBUG c.g.e.a.i.EhCacheInterceptor - Generated key '-1043428721379252' for invocation: ReflectiveMethodInvocation:
13:45:02.927 [main] DEBUG PersonServiceTest  - Done
```

But the output of my war (running through tomcat7/eclipse wtp) is:

```
   DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory Configuring ehcache from InputStream
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.BeanHandler Ignoring ehcache attribute xmlns:xsi
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.BeanHandler Ignoring ehcache attribute xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil propertiesString is null.
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper No CacheManagerEventListenerFactory class specified. Skipping...
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache No BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class specified. Skipping...
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache CacheWriter factory not configured. Skipping...
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper No CacheExceptionHandlerFactory class specified. Skipping...
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache No BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class specified. Skipping...
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache CacheWriter factory not configured. Skipping...
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper No CacheExceptionHandlerFactory class specified. Skipping...
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore Initialized net.sf.ehcache.store.NotifyingMemoryStore for deviceCache
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl Mocking Pass-Through Statistic: LOCAL_OFFHEAP_SIZE
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl Mocking Pass-Through Statistic: LOCAL_OFFHEAP_SIZE_BYTES
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl Mocking Pass-Through Statistic: LOCAL_DISK_SIZE
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl Mocking Pass-Through Statistic: LOCAL_DISK_SIZE_BYTES
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl Mocking Pass-Through Statistic: WRITER_QUEUE_LENGTH
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl Mocking Pass-Through Statistic: REMOTE_SIZE
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl Mocking Operation Statistic: OFFHEAP_GET
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl Mocking Operation Statistic: OFFHEAP_PUT
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl Mocking Operation Statistic: OFFHEAP_REMOVE
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl Mocking Operation Statistic: DISK_GET
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl Mocking Operation Statistic: DISK_PUT
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl Mocking Operation Statistic: DISK_REMOVE
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl Mocking Operation Statistic: XA_COMMIT
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl Mocking Operation Statistic: XA_ROLLBACK
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl Mocking Operation Statistic: XA_RECOVERY
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache Initialised cache: deviceCache
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper CacheDecoratorFactory not configured. Skipping for 'personCache'.
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'personCache'.
DEBUG com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl Adding CACHE advised method 'detect' with attribute: CacheableAttributeImpl [cacheInstanceResolver=com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.resolver.SingletonCacheableCacheResolver@7a1b0c08, cacheKeyGenerator=HashCodeCacheKeyGenerator [includeMethod=true, includeParameterTypes=true, useReflection=false, checkforCycles=false], parameterMask=ParameterMask [mask=[]]]
Apr 3, 2013 2:03:12 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
DEBUG com.mycompany.Controller trying to get resource'
DEBUG com.mycompany.PersonServiceImpl Missed 
DEBUG com.mycompany.Controller got person'
DEBUG com.mycompany.Controller trying to get resource'
DEBUG com.mycompany.PersonServiceImpl Missed 
DEBUG com.mycompany.Controller got person'
```

So my question is, why does it work in my unit test, and not webapp? And how would I use the spring annotation instead of the googlecode annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I had an interface, I had the @Cacheable annotation on the implementation class. Once I moved it to the interface class, it was cached.

Answer (score 10):

Your `PersonService` service is not implementing an interface. Ehcache-spring-annotations requires an interface, as described in the [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions):

> Requirement 1: your class MUST
>   implement some (any) interface. If your class does not implement an
>   interface, this project will not be able to create a Proxy to mimic
>   your class and apply the cache semantics around your annotated
>   methods.

Comment: I have the same problem even with it implementing an interface

Comment: Is been a while since I used it but I vaguely remember having to add a dummy method argument to one of my cached no-args methods so that Ehcache could matchup the cached return value with that method. Worth a try....

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable the eh cache annotation in your spring context xml or Spring config file. for example

```
<ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" />
```